Can't build Vite project in Docker container - Unknown node type: undefined
When I execute my Dockerfile, at building stage I have this error:
 > [build-stage 6/6] RUN yarn run build:
0.894 yarn run v1.22.22
0.983 $ tsc --noEmit && vite build
2.110 vite v5.3.3 building for production...
2.241 transforming...
2.254 Trace
2.254     at convertNode (file:///app/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:13043:17)
2.254     at convertNodeList (file:///app/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:13061:34)
2.254     at Array.arrayExpression (file:///app/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:12578:25)      
2.254     at convertNode (file:///app/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:13050:28)
2.254     at convertNodeList (file:///app/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:13061:34)
2.254     at Array.sequenceExpression (file:///app/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:12947:28)   
2.254     at convertNode (file:///app/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:13050:28)
2.254     at Array.property (file:///app/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:12922:22)
2.254     at convertNode (file:///app/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:13050:28)
2.254     at convertProgram (file:///app/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:12405:12)
2.255 ✓ 1 modules transformed.
2.258 x Build failed in 73ms
2.258 error during build:
2.258 Unknown node type: undefined
2.258     at convertNode (file:///app/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:13044:15)
2.258     at convertNodeList (file:///app/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:13061:34)
2.258     at Array.arrayExpression (file:///app/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:12578:25)      
2.258     at convertNode (file:///app/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:13050:28)
2.258     at convertNodeList (file:///app/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:13061:34)
2.258     at Array.sequenceExpression (file:///app/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:12947:28)   
2.258     at convertNode (file:///app/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:13050:28)
2.258     at Array.property (file:///app/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:12922:22)
2.258     at convertNode (file:///app/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:13050:28)
2.258     at convertProgram (file:///app/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:12405:12)
2.297 error Command failed with exit code 1.

Locally on my machine (Windows 11) yarn run build works well.
Dockerfile:
FROM node:lts-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN yarn
COPY . .
RUN yarn run build
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["yarn", "run", "build"]

docker-compose.yaml:
version: "3.4"
services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
    container_name: docker-mern-frontend-by-nginx
    environment:
      - VITE_SERVER_ENDPOINT=http://localhost:5000
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/usr/src/frontend
      - frontend_node_modules:/usr/src/frontend/node_modules/

volumes:
  mongo_data:
  frontend_node_modules:

vite.config.ts:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
// import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  base: '/',
  plugins: [react()],
  define: {
    VITE_SERVER_ENDPOINT: process.env.VITE_SERVER_ENDPOINT,
  },
  preview: {
    port: 3000,
    strictPort: true,
  },
  server: {
    port: 3000,
    strictPort: true,
    host: true,
    origin: 'http://0.0.0.0:3000',
    watch: {
      usePolling: true,
    }
  }
});

package.json:
{
  "name": "test",
  "author": {
    "name": "Dolzhikov Denis",
  },
  "repository": {
    "url": "https://github.com/DenisDolzhikov/"
  },
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc --noEmit && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.5",
    "@fontsource/roboto": "^5.0.13",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.16.1",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.172",
    "@mui/material": "^5.16.1",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.2.6",
    "async-mutex": "^0.5.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-intl": "^6.6.8",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.24.1",
    "react-toastify": "^10.0.5",
    "redux": "^5.0.1",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "scss": "^0.2.4",
    "uuid": "^10.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^22.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
    "@types/uuid": "^10.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^7.13.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^7.13.1",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.3.1",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.7",
    "rollup": "^4.19.1",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "vite": "^5.3.1"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "@rollup/rollup-linux-x64-gnu": "4.6.1"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "vite": {
      "rollup": "npm:@rollup/wasm-node"
    }
  }
}

When I did searching solution, I added optional dependencies and overrides in my package.json.
 "optionalDependencies": {
    "@rollup/rollup-linux-x64-gnu": "4.6.1"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "vite": {
      "rollup": "npm:@rollup/wasm-node"
    }
  }

Also I changed my vite.config.ts, I did add this:
define: {
  VITE_SERVER_ENDPOINT: process.env.VITE_SERVER_ENDPOINT,
},
server: {
  port: 3000,
  strictPort: true,
  host: true,
  origin: 'http://0.0.0.0:3000',
  watch: {
    usePolling: true,
  }
}

and I added volumes for node_modules. All of this doesn't work for me.

Do you have a .dockerignore file that keeps your host's node_modules directory out of the image?  The volumes: block that you have hides absolutely everything in the image, so it doesn't really matter whether the build in the image works or not; if you're intent on running the code on the host, can you also use a host-based Node interpreter, without introducing Docker into it?
